# Which definition of "situation" applies in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> The professor gave them a piece of advice."Remember," he said to them, "the four of you may be proficient, each in your own subject, but if you don't have the sense **to act suitably to the time and circumstance of a situation**, you may have to go hungry."

The sentences are taken from the story *Too Much Knowledge Maketh Fools*.

When I look up the meaning of the word "[situation](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/situation)" in a dictionary, I find some definitions but I cannot decide which one should be chosen. I think it might be "a state of affairs".

Answer (score 1):

In this context it would mean the *condition in which one finds oneself*. Obviously, these conditions can be variable and have distinct difficulties associated with them, and it is these *conditions* I think that the professor is emphasizing.

Answer (score 0):

"The combination of circumstances at a given moment" will be the right choice in this case. It can be expressed in other words in different dictionaries, so I think your guess is correct.